# Snowflake Pipe - adding a timestamp on every ingest

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the a snowflake Pipe that copies json data into a table every time I get an SNS message from AWS. It's important that I also use a file format that properly decodes the json.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE stage.table_pipe
AUTO_INGEST = TRUE
AWS_SNS_TOPIC = 'arn:::'
AS COPY INTO raw.table (json) FROM @raw.stage/ FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = raw.json_gz);
```

I want to add an additional column to the table I'm ingesting in with a timestamp of every ingest.

I tried rewriting the pipe to add this functionality, but it doesn't work. The COPY INTO part:

```
COPY INTO raw.table
FROM (
    SELECT $1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_MODIFIED
    FROM @raw.stage
    )
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = raw.json_gz);
```

If I remove the last line with the file_format it works, but doesn't decode the json using the format.

Also tried:

`AS COPY INTO raw.table(json), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_MODIFIED FROM @raw.stage FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = raw.json_gz);`

which is incorrect syntax.

Is there an approach I could use to get this working correctly?

Comment: could you please try to use copy command like this ```COPY INTO raw.table FROM (SELECT $1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_MODIFIED FROM @raw.stage (file_format => raw.json_gz));```

Comment: Please add that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: done, thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment the correct syntax of the COPY command for what you are trying to achieve is as follows:

```sql
COPY INTO raw.table FROM (
SELECT $1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_MODIFIED FROM @raw.stage (file_format => raw.json_gz)
);
```

Please note, that this implementation will give you the timestamp value generated at the moment of the compilation of the COPY statement. In some use cases it might not be precisely enough. You can also consider leveraging the metadata for the stage files, that Snowflake automatically [generates](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata).

See Example 3 on the link above for the detailed example.